# How to clone a repository in github that was created using laravel 4.2 to work with laravel 5 without having to upgrade the files of the repository?

Tags: git, github, laravel-4, laravel-5

I installed laravel 5 in a new notebook and would like to edit the code I have in a github repository that was wrote using laravel 4.2

I'm able to create a laravel 4 project using following command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name ~4.2.0 --prefer-dist
```

but when I try to clone my repository it doesn't work. It's said that some files are missing.

So my question is: How can I clone a repository in github that was created using laravel 4.2 to work with laravel 5 without having to upgrade the files of the repository?

I don't / I can't update to laravel 5 because some plugins don't support laravel 5 yet.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use Laravel 4 in your project? You can't use Laravel 5 without updating any files

Comment: Because I have some projects in Laravel 4 and now some in 5. :-\
And by the way, how could I install only Laravel 4 with composer? The command in the docs install only the last version: Laravel 5.

Comment: you can't. L4 differs in application structure from L5.

Comment: Yes we can! :-)
We can install Laravel 5.
Then we have to clone the repository that was written with Laravel 4.
And then use in terminal "composer install" inside the folder of the project you've just cloned. It will install all necessary dependencies.
That's it: so simply as Laravel is. Now we have a notebook with Laravel 5 and a project with Laravel 4.
Credits to a friend of mine.